# Parsing SQL embedded in codebase

Tags: sql, parsing, sql-parser

I'm working with a codebase that has a lot of embedded SQL queries in strings and separate code files which makes it difficult to document data requirements for the application. There are some basic tools like [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse) in python and rather advanced tools like [sqlparser](https://eng.uber.com/queryparser/) from Uber. Ideally I could get some sort of data object that would contain a list of files and query object tokens that would be easy to generate a flat list of [File, Table, Column] for all SQL queries in the code base.

Comment: databases don't have files.  If you want a list of the tables and columns there are meta data ways to do that --- what platform are you using and what exactly do you need to do?

Comment: The SQL is in the Python codebase. Ideally the SQL would be in the database ;)